# Regex match each line that contains character

Tags: java, regex, match, newline

How can I make a regex that matches all new-line-characters ONLY when it begins with a " ' " character?
Example:

```
'Hello World > Match "/n" after "d"
Hello World > No match

'Test > Match "/n" after "t"
Test > No match

'''''Xample > Match "/n" after "e"
Xample > No match

WOW 'He > Match "/n" after "e"
```

Thanks in advance ;)

Edit: All that I want are place tags on the BEGINNING and at the ENDING of each line that has this "comments". Like this:

```
WOW <blabla>'Hello<blabla>
```

The beginning I can just normally replace " ' " with " ' ", but the ending is a bit more difficult.

Comment: what if the last line begins with `'`?

Comment: check if a line begins with a single quote `^'.*`

Comment: There will always be a empty line after a " ' " character.

Comment: Why you want to match `\n` in th last line in your input where `'` is in the middle?

Comment: Because this is Basic lanuage and I want to add color tags on the final. At the beginning I can just replace " ' " with " <color>' ". But at the end it's a bit more dificult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this pattern

```
^([^']*)('+)(.*)(\r?\n|$)
```

and replace w/ `$1<tag>$2$3</tag>$4`
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/gO0bG4/3)

Comment: I have used this to perform highlighting tags like "If" and "Then" too, using: 
^([^Then]*)(Then+)(.*)(\r?\n|$) 
But I don't want to highlight if it has a " ' " character in front of it. Have you a solution for this too? @alphabravo

Comment: no, you haven't understood me right. I want this Regex ^([^Then]*)(Then+)(.*)(\r?\n|$) But that don't higlight any "Then" when it's commented code " ' ".

Comment: @Fusseldieb Please post valid and non-valid examples to match and expected result

Comment: 'Then > Not add tags                                               
Then > Add tags

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand , `Please post valid and non-valid examples to match and expected result`

Comment: I mean: `blablabla 'Then` Don't match "Then" ....... `Then 'blablabla Then` Match only first Then ....... I want to match all "Then" before the "'" character and none after him.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
(^|\s)'.+$
```

example:
http://regex101.com/r/gO0bG4/1